# Facebook PHP SDK conflicting autoload function

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to implement the FaceBook PHP SDK into a project that uses a `__autoload()` function already.

The source code for the existing `__autoload()` function is:

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    require_once 'class/class.'.$class_name.'.php';
}
```

It is conflicting somehow with the `spl_autoload_register(function ($class))` in the FaceBook's PHP SDK `autoload.php`, however I seem not to be able to find a workaround.

I know that `__autoload()` is deprecated and might be removed in the future, so it might be time to change it to `spl_autoload_register()`, however I don't know how.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) about spl_autoload_register?

Comment: Yes I have. Based on the number of questions about this subject here and elsewhere it's not very clear. At least not to me and some others...

Comment: The documentation is provided with some examples. What is your problem with it?

Comment: Problem is that I can't find a solution, no matter how I tried to implement the `spl_autoload_register()` as a replacement for `__autoload()`... If you know a solution please post an answer...